# node.js .. Changing source code but not reflecting in web page

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, pm2

I am changing the code in my node js project and I stop and start pm2 and the changes are note reflected in the the webpage.

Here is my pm2.config.yml

```
apps:
  - name: 'api'
    script: 'yarn start'
    cwd: './api'
    log_file: '~/logs/web/app.log'
    env:
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
  - name: 'worker'
    script: 'yarn start-worker'
    cwd: './api'
    log_file: '~/logs/web/worker.log'
    env:
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
```

Comment: Most likely it is cached by your browser. In Chrome you can temporarily disable cache if you have the developer tools open: open the "Network" tab and there should be a checkbox to disable cache. Alternatively you can clear cache in any browser

Comment: Did you even reload the page?

Comment: Yes.. Clear browsing history and everything

Comment: Even rebooted the server

Comment: Just tried connecting from a completely different machine and the changes are not there

Comment: Turns out code needs to be compiled with yarn.. So yarn build fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to get this working using yarn . It had to be compiled using 'yarn build'

I am not sure why my original question was edited....